# 'penance' vs 'penitence'

Tags: english, etymology, latin, french

> [penance (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=penance&searchmode=none) [←] 
>       late 13c., "religious discipline or self-mortification as a token of repentance and as atonement for some sin," from Anglo-French penaunce, **Old French peneance** (12c.), from Latin `pænitentia` (see [penitence](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=penitence&allowed_in_frame=0)). Transferred sense is recorded from c. 1300.
>
> [penitence (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=penitence&allowed_in_frame=0) [←] 
>       c. 1200, from Old French penitence (11c.)
>   and directly from Latin `paenitentia` "repentance," noun of condition
>   from paenitentum (nominative paenitens) "penitent,"

In modern English, 'penance' differs from 'penitence'.
However,  modern French lacks a cognate of the English 'penance'.
Instead, ['penance'](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/english-french/penance/601094) seems to be translated as « pénitence » (nf).
Per contra, per the bold above, Old French did contain a cognate of the English 'penance'.

So how did the same Latin etymon `paenitentia` evolve into all this complexity?
 Please expose and explain all hidden, missing semantic drifts and links.

I'm unversed in Latin, but I noticed that Etymonline above spells `paenitentia` differently: first with [the ash grapheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86#Usage), then 'ae' separately. Please advise.

Comment: My guess is this is a split of the word between popular and expert usage, _peneance_ would be the popular term used by everybody while _penitence_ would be restricted to theological usage.